# Tumblr API Tagged Method - URL not responding corrently

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, tumblr

I'm trying to use Tumblr's API to pull posts with a specific hashtag from an individual blog.

This URL will pull the five most recent posts from the blog in question:

https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/dbudell.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&limit=5&callback=?

I had a look at Tumblr's [Tagged Method documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method), and then built this url to pull the most recent 5 posts with the tag "landscape" (the difference is that I added **&tagged?tag=landscape** after the api key):

https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/dbudell.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&tagged?tag=landscape&limit=5&callback=?

Unfortunately, however, this link does just like the former and returns the last five posts, regardless of hashtag. Any thoughts on how I might fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Hello again everyone,

Turns out I was trying to combine two different endpoints by pulling from an individual blog and at the same time calling **&tagged**, which searches through all posts on Tumblr. By removing that snippet and just **&tag=landscape** instead, I was able to correctly search for posts from a specific blog with a certain hashtag.

Have a lovely day!